# XBMC settings sync on Raspbmc

Tags: raspbmc, setup, kodi, filesystem, settings

How can I sync the settings of XBMC on my Raspbmc with the XBMC which I've installed on a computer or Android phone, on the same LAN?

Answer (score 3):

All plugins, settings, etc. are stored in `~/.xbmc`. So you just need to sync that folder, for example using the `rsync` command:

https://www.google.com/search?q=rsync+synchronize+remote+folder

Answer (score 0):

I've found some solutions, still not tested:

Sync through MySQL: [http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=HOW-TO:Sync_multiple_libraries](http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=HOW-TO%3aSync_multiple_libraries)

Android sync through Dropbox: http://www.freewaregenius.com/how-to-automatically-sync-your-pc-folders-with-your-android/

Edit:

The working solution I've found is to use the XBMC Backup Add-on:
[http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=Add-on:XBMC_Backup](http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=Add-on%3aXBMC_Backup)